# How to fill progress bar value automatically base on function progress

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, autofill

im trying to do a progress bar using tkinter and i want to the progress fill automatically base on the percentage of the code without telling it prg.['value] += x
how can i do it?(filled upon the percentage of completed level of the function)
Thanks

Comment: The exact percentage is silly and inaccurate. Instead, add checkpoints (i.e. 3 distinct checkpoints : 33% 67% 100%) and set your tkinter progress bar like that. If you want a completed code, you might need to show some more effort within writing the question.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama do need exact code to add it manually tnx

Comment: there is no method to do it automatically. In your function you have to add some code which changes progressbar or it put value in some (global) variable and other function/process can get it and use to change value in progressbar.